# Problems to import ISO20022 E-Repository into Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, metamodel, ecore

I am trying to open the ISO20022 e-repository in Eclipse.

I already imported the .ecore file and generated the plugins, but when I try to open the .iso20022 file eclipse stops responding.

I tried with Eclipse 2019-06 and Eclipse Mars 2 for Windows.

What I'm doing:

1 - Downloaded the .ecore and .iso20022 files at https://www.iso20022.org/e_dictionary.page

2 - I opened eclipse and created a new EMF Project. During the project creation wizard I imported the .ecore file.

3 - With the project created, I opened the file ISO20022.genmodel and right-clicked the root of the tree "ISO20022", and select the option "Generate All" to create the plugins, so the projects ".edit", ".editor" and ".tests" were created.

4 - I right clicked on the ".editor" project and selected "Run As -> Eclipse Application", and a new instance of Eclipse runtime opened.

5 - In this new instance of eclipse I tried to open the .iso20022 file, then Eclipse stops responding. I also tried to create a new project and then import the .iso20022, but eclipse always stops responding when trying to open the file.

Has anyone opened the ISO20022 e-repository in Eclipse? Am I doing right?

Answer (score 0):

The file is bigger than usual (350k lines), have you implemented the tip given on the page you linked?

> https://www.iso20022.org/sites/default/files/documents/eRepositories/Metamodel/Eclipse_plugin_tip.pdf

Comment: It worked! Thanks!
But now, how do I add my business components to the design view? I'm trying to drag and drop, but it's not working.